# SynchronizeFromQField just opens the QField project

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geopackage, qfield, qfieldsync

I am using QField with QGIS. I don't understand the purpose of the tool *Synchronize from QField*.

I successfully created a QGIS project with relative paths (with data from a geopackage), successfully synced it with QField, opened and edited it on my mobile. After that, I transferred everything back to my PC.

I reopened the original QGIS project and specified the folder of the QField project in the SynchronizeFromQField tool menu (as described in the [QField Documentation](https://qfield.org/docs/synchronise/qfieldsync.html)).

A process then started (loading bar was displayed and layers disappeared from the layers window). But it seems that simply the QField project file was opened. After the process, the data paths are changed to those of the QField Geopackage.

I can just open the QField project in QGIS and get the same result.

The changes made on the mobile are all correctly present in the QField Geopackage and are all correctly displayed in QGIS.
What do I need the sync function for, if I can just open the Qfield project like this?

tested with QGIS 3.22 / QField v1.10.0 / QField Sync 4.0.0-BETA17

Comment: It depends on your workflow. If you're using data from a postgres database for instance, you probably won't want to take the entire dataset with you but rather a subset. In this instance, Qfield syncs the subset back into the master dataset.

Comment: But it does not work with local geopackages?

Answer (score 1):

The synchronize tool from QField is supposed to sync your collected data back to your master dataset.

QField only works with .qgs files, so when you save your project make sure you select .qgs and not .qgz.

Then create two directories e.g. import and export

- Save the packege for QField into the export directory
- Move export directory to tablet
- Sync with master dataset: copy the export directory from the tablet to the import
  directory on your computer.
- Synchronize Project on QGIS: select the export directory, which you just copied
  in your import directory.

There is a [tutorial](https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/lesson_1.html#Setup) on how to set up QField snycronization.

Comment: I don't think saving the project as a .qgs is necessary anymore;  I have a number of (small) projects where I have forgotten to do this, and packaging and synchronization appear to work fine (and one, currently where they don't, for some as yet unknown reason, but saving the project as .qgs does not appear to help).